# How to do faceted search in riak via erlang client?

Tags: search, erlang, riak

I am developing a product using Erlang and riak.

Now I encounter a problem on faceted search on riak.

For example, how to get the facet of given secondary index?

Answer (score 2):

[Secondary indexes](http://docs.basho.com/riak/2.0.0/dev/using/2i/) don't support facets. Solr can do facets, but to use that you need to enable [Riak Search 2](http://docs.basho.com/riak/2.0.0/dev/using/search/) and send the appropriate query.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a query sample for it?

Comment: There are some samples here, https://github.com/basho/riak-ruby-client#riak-search-examples, with a link pointing to more.